# PHPSVN on CentOS giving "Not Found" error on svn_commit

Tags: php, svn, centos

I have a setup wherein admin need to be able to edit .phtml files.  However, since the files are all under subversion control, I want to use [PHPSVN](http://php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php) to commit the files after they are edited.

The production server is CentOS.  As I use [svn2web](http://svn2web.sourceforge.net/), I have my working copies separate from the actual file-system in a directory called */home/working-copies*.

Each file is editable through a textarea in a form.  When user submits the form, the contents of the textarea are written over the working copy file using [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Ideally, the file would then be committed via [svn_commit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.svn-commit.php).  However, instead of committing I get an error of "Not Found".   If I attempt to save/svn_commit again, I get an error of "Attempted to lock an already-locked dir".  The file is successfully overwritten, but the commit fails.

I then must manually (via command line) execute svn cleanup.  When the working copy is unlocked, I am also able to manually commit successfully.

I have been unable to find any documentation of the "Not Found" error, but I am quite sure it's originating from the svn_commit.  I am also sure that the attempt to commit the file is what locks the directory.

1. SVN and the PHPSVN extension are both installed.
2. [svn_client_version()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-client-version.php) returns the correct version of SVN on the server (which seems to indicate that the PHPSVN extension is working... maybe?)
3. The entire process does work on my local Ubuntu machine. Is this perhaps an issue with PHPSVN on the CentOS server?

I am not sure how to even go about debugging this issue further and I appreciate any input.  Thank you.

**Edit (2013-07-23)**
While I still haven't managed to solve the issue using the PHPSVN extension, I was able to use exec().  Here is the syntax I used, in case it helps anyone in the future:

```
// The flags used help get around any SSL certificate errors.

exec('cd /home/working-copies/testfolder; svn commit "test.phtml" --username "username" --password "pw" --no-auth-cache --non-interactive --trust-server-cert -m "test svn" 2>&1', $output, $returnStatus);

// Print the output to help debug.

if ( $returnStatus )
{
   print_r($output);
}
```

I am still very curious as to the "Not Found" error I was getting while using PHPSVN, so I will leave this question open in hopes of finding an answer.  Thanks again.